# Worklight: Webservice inside customization WAR

Tags: web-services, ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possible we can create Webservice inside Worklight customization WAR file? Purpose is to give access to an external application user some resources like adapters from worklight.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible but I don't think I would suggest it. Write your webservice to run independently of Worklight. Adapters can still connect to your web service even if the web service runs on an entirely separate server.

Let the Worklight WAR be Worklight and let the web service be a web service.